# What are methods/attributes in dmidecode module in python?

Tags: python, python-module

I need to know about my system's hardware as described in BIOS and use it in a python program. So I came to know about this python module dmidecode and I installed it in my machine. But I cannot understand the methods in it. For instance :

```
>>> dir(dmidecode)
['TYPE', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', '_get_output', '_parse_handle_section', '_show', 'parse_dmi', 'profile']
```

Now, when I am trying to access the individual methods, it is giving the following errors:

```
>>> dmidecode._parse_handle_section()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: _parse_handle_section() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

>>> dmidecode._show()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: _show() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

>>> dmidecode.parse_dmi()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: parse_dmi() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Now, the real problem is that, I cannot find any good tutorial to study and understand the usage of these methods.

So any help or links will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try invoking `help(dmidecode)` in the python interpreter? Most packages include internal documentation.

Comment: Yes. It is giving the following output : 



Help on module dmidecode:

NAME
    dmidecode

FILE
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dmidecode.py

FUNCTIONS
    parse_dmi(content)
        Parse the whole dmidecode output.
        Returns a list of tuples of (type int, value dict).
    
    profile()

DATA
    TYPE = {0: 'bios', 1: 'system', 2: 'base board', 3: 'chassis', 4: 'pro...
    __version__ = '0.8.1'

VERSION
    0.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives:

- You can use `pydoc <module>` to access the module's documentation from the system shell, and `pydoc <module>.<method>` to access a specific method docstring.
- You can use `help(<module>)` to access the same documentation from the Python shell, and `help(<module>.<method>)` for a method docstring.
- You can use `%pinfo <module>` and `%pinfo2 <module>` to access the docstrings and read the source code from the IPython shell, which is an alternative to the normal shell you are using. This also works for methods.

If there is no documentation or docstrings whatsoever, then your only option is to read the code with IPython and `%pinfo2`.

And a word of advice: in Python, a method which has a `_` prepended *usually* is meant to be private, while methods starting and ending with `__` are called "magic" and are "even more private", so to speak.

You can always access everything, but from the looks of the `dir` call, you should concentrate on the `parse_dmi` and `profile` functions.